# How to make matplotlib handle custom class "units"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make my class compatible with [matplotlib's units](https://matplotlib.org/api/units_api.html#matplotlib.units.ConversionInterface) and facing an unexpected behaviour.

Here is a simplified version of my custom class, that is not a subclass of numpy's ndarray :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.units as units

class Toto:
    def __init__(self, value_like, unit_like):
        self.value_like = value_like # typically a scalar or array
        self.unit_like = unit_like # a string describing the unit

    def __array__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array(self.value_like, *args, **kwargs)

# To test if plot as expected, without units handling
arr_x = Toto(np.arange(5), "meter")
arr_y = Toto(np.arange(5), "second")
plt.plot(arr_x, arr_y)
```

Notice I added a `__array__` method in order to make it "plottable" with matplotlib (if not, I get a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Toto'` exception, when numpy tries to cast Toto with `array(toto_instance, float)`). I suspect my problem actually come from this method but I can't figure out why/how. Anyway, moving on the actual problem :

Now I followed the [example in the doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/units_api.html#matplotlib.units.ConversionInterface) to make a conversion-interface for my Toto class:

```py
class TotoConverter(units.ConversionInterface):

    @staticmethod
    def convert(value, unit, axis):
        'Convert a toto object value to a scalar or array'
        old_toto_unit = axis.get_unit()
        # stupid computation to determine new_unit (simpler for a MWE)
        new_unit = old_toto_unit
        new_toto = Toto(value, new_unit)
        return new_toto.value_like

    @staticmethod
    def axisinfo(unit, axis):
        return units.AxisInfo(label=str(unit))

    @staticmethod
    def default_units(x, axis):
        'Return the default unit for x or None'
        return getattr(x, 'unit_like', None)
```

In the end, I add the conversion interface of my class to matplotlib's registry of conversion interfaces:

```py
units.registry[Toto] = TotoConverter()
```

**Then the problem :**
At this point, I should get the unit on the label when plotting Toto instances, but I get the same result as before defining and registering my unit conversion-interface. Why is that ?

I suspect the conversion object is never called since my Toto instances are converted into ndarray but I'm not sure

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean something like this, where you have a list/array of `Toto`s, and not a `Toto` of values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.units as units

class Toto:
    def __init__(self, value_like, unit_like):
        self.value_like = value_like # typically a scalar or array
        self.unit_like = unit_like # a string describing the unit

class TotoConverter(units.ConversionInterface):

    @staticmethod
    def convert(value, unit, axis):
        if isinstance(value, Toto):
            return value.value_like
        else:
            return [toto.value_like for toto in value]

    @staticmethod
    def axisinfo(unit, axis):
        return units.AxisInfo(label=str(unit))

    @staticmethod
    def default_units(x, axis):
        'Return the default unit for x or None'
        if isinstance(x, Toto):
            return getattr(x, 'unit_like', None)
        else:
            return getattr(x[0], 'unit_like', None)
```

Then register and use it,

```
units.registry[Toto] = TotoConverter()


arr_x = [Toto(i, "meter") for i in range(5)]
arr_y = [Toto(i, "second") for i in range(5)]

plt.plot(arr_x, arr_y)            #use lists of Totos
plt.axhline(Toto(2, "second"))    # use Toto scalars
plt.xlim(Toto(-1, "meter"), None) # use Toto scalars

plt.show()
```

Comment: No, I really mean to plot 2 Toto objects, whose values are arrays, like in the example before defining the interface : ```arr_x = Toto(np.arange(5), "meter")
arr_y = Toto(np.arange(5), "second")
plt.plot(arr_x, arr_y)``` but I want their units to be added to the labels.

Comment: That would be pretty complicated. See https://matplotlib.org/gallery/units/basic_units.html for a start with it.

Comment: I am only trying to understand how can a class be plotted (which requires to be convertible into array) AND also be caught by the unit interface (which requires to be of the type Toto)